# Will Compiz in Unity use Emerald as its window decorator?

Tags: unity, compiz, emerald

Sorry if that's a dumb question.

Answer (score 7):

Unity with Compiz will use the [Compiz GTK window decorator](http://wiki.compiz.org/Decorators/GTKWindowDecorator), but it should be possible to replace that manually with [Emerald](http://wiki.compiz.org/Decorators/Emerald) if desired.

Answer (score 1):

Emerald is no longer being actively maintained, and a replacement is being worked on. However, ubuntu has always used GTK-Window decorator as Alex said, so no.

Comment: Also, using another window decorator would mean that there have to be made 2 identically looking themes, one for Emerald (or its replacement) and one that's metacity-compatible for those who can't use Compiz.

Comment: good point <extra chars thing is annoying <-- typed to allow comment to post lol>.

Comment: that's done for clever comments (like mine :-P)